# Using XPathNodeIterator

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to interate through the below xml sample using

```
XPathNodeIterator nodes = xPathNav.Select("z:row");

while(nodes.MoveNext())  
{
}
```

this gives the error "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed"

Can anyone advise the best way to loop through the xml or point me in the right direction of where i am going wrong

thanks

S

[image: sample xml]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass a namespace manager as a second argument to Select, a bit like what is described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316913 (except that it's an example with SelectNodes).

Comment: thanks, but the namespace is the part i am having problems with

Comment: Would xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("z", "#RowsetSchema"); (assuming you built a manager) work?